# Copying a worksheet to a new workbook but only carrying over one macro. Is this possible?

Tags: excel, vba

One of my reporting workbooks splits data into individual sheets, which then go to individual offices.  The issue is that my reporting workbooks all have a ton of macros that I use, but that I don't want others getting into or getting a hold of.  I would like it to carry over a few things, mainly worksheet_change and close events (or alternatively a macro).  Basically each individual office has to verify and document anything that needs to be changed.  I've been up in the air about what method to try to use, if either is possible. My choices are:

1) Include a date column that updates via something in a workbook change event and a user form prompt to enter their name as "last edited by" as a before close event; or
2) Include a macro with a command button that the user clicks on to bring up a user form that automatically includes the current date and a box for them to enter their name. When the user clicks ok the form closes, the workbook saves and closes.

Assuming I don't want to have to set up each individual workbook with the same code for this, is it possible to create all of this in my reporting workbook and then just create a macro that creates the individual workbook(which I can already do) and then copies only the coding/macro for the specified task above(which I have no idea where to start on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy/paste some VBA code from a workbook to another using this procedure:

```
Sub CopyModule(SourceWB As Workbook, strModuleName As String, _
    TargetWB As Workbook)
' copies a module from one workbook to another
' example: 
' CopyModule Workbooks("Book1.xls"), "Module1", _
'    Workbooks("Book2.xls")
Dim strFolder As String, strTempFile As String
    strFolder = SourceWB.Path
    If Len(strFolder) = 0 Then strFolder = CurDir
    strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    strTempFile = strFolder & "~tmpexport.bas"
    On Error Resume Next
    SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents(strModuleName).Export strTempFile
    TargetWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import strTempFile
    Kill strTempFile
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And then use:

```
CopyModule Workbooks("Book1.xls"), "Module1", Workbooks("Book2.xls")
```

found [here](http://www.exceltip.com/show_tip/Modules,_Class_Modules_in_VBA/Copy_modules_from_one_workbook_to_another_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/501.html)

Comment: Like this.  Going to tinker with it in my test folder, but gave a nod for the answer. Thanks!